# torch.tensor results are registered as constants in the trace

Tags: python, pytorch, bayesian

I am trying to fit a baayesian linear regression in python using pytorch. But the parameter values that are being sampled from the posterior distribution are all same for each parameter. That is for the slope parameter 1000 samples are being sampled and all the 1000 values of slope are the same. While running the code getting this below warning.
TracerWarning: torch.tensor results are registered as constants in the trace. You can safely ignore this warning if you use this function to create tensors out of constant variables that would be the same every time you call this function. In any other case, this might cause the trace to be incorrect.

What does this warning suggest and how to resolve the issue of getting the same sample value for the parameters?